# Renewal process: Stationary and independent increments?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stationarity, poisson-process

For a renewal process, we know that the inter-arrivals are independent but not exponentially distributed, as opposed to the Poisson process for which the inter-arrivals are exponential.

We also know that the counting process $N_t$ that follows a Poisson process has stationary independent increments. I wonder if this property holds for a renewal process? If not, under what conditions does it hold?

Answer (score 1):

a renewal process {} could be either stationary incremented or not stationary incremented.

If {} is a stationary increment process, it is then without memory, thus, it is a poisson process. Classic bulb renewal process falls into this category, it's both a poisson process and a renewal process.

If {} is not a stationary increment process, this could also be a case. As in, a bunch of bulbs get renewed with worse and worse batches, thus their life distribution gets shortened over time, and therefore their increment(Pr{one or more event happen in (t,t+Δt)}), while maintaining independence on each other, is dependent on the t.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So, in general, we cannot say that
\begin{equation}
 N_T - N_t \sim N_{T-t}
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
 N_T - N_t \quad \text{is independent of } \quad N_t
\end{equation}

Comment: Indeed. And if by the first equation you actually mean $$ _T−_t∼(T-t) $$, we cannot say that either generally for renewal processes.